# Convert hexadecimal string to an integer

Tags: c#, hex

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32('o');
Byte[]  b =  new Byte[] { ( byte)value };
File.WriteAllBytes(Default.ProjectsPath , b);
```

when I open the file it displays `o`, I want to write the byte value to the file?

Comment: What is the exception? On which line? What is `value`? What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the`0x` then convert:

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32("0xFE".Substring(2), 16);
```

Comment: that gives i = 254
I want i = 0xFE

Comment: Your original `String.Format("0x{0:X}", 254);` does that, no?

Comment: @HazemAhmed `0xFE` is hexadecimal notation of `254` which represents as 4 bits. You want `0xFE` as a result from an input as `254`?

Comment: @SonerGönül I know that I just want the 0x representation stored in i

Comment: That's not possible, `i` is an integer; it cannot store *strings* which is what "0xFE" is (the x is not a number!) - It does not matter however, store the the integer value and convert to hex whenever you need to *display* it.

Comment: Exactly @SonerGönül !

Comment: @AlexK. you can type int i = 0xFE ;

Comment: Yes, but not  `int i = "0xFE";` - Without the quotes the compiler understands that 0xFE is integer 254. Without quotes 0x is just a *representation* of 254 - they are identical.  Perhaps you should expand your question with more details of what you want to do

Comment: I want to write 0xFE as byte to a file using File.WriteAllBytes()  @AlexK.

Comment: (Without quotes) 0xFE **is** 254 - so - `new byte[] { 0xFE }`; and `new byte[] { 254 };` are the same; so just use 254

Comment: when i open the file it is different

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ToInt16(string)` will not be able to convert strings that start with '0x', even though that's the correct notation for base 16 numbers. If you want to use your solution, you will need to remove the "0x" from the string conversion. Replace

```
string s=String.Format("0x{0:X}", value);
```

with

```
string s=String.Format("{0:x}", value);
```

Or you can use Alex K.'s idea and replace

```
int x=Convert.ToInt16(s);
```

with

```
int x=Convert.ToInt16(s.Substring(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are the one producing the string in the first place then like *Alex Barac* suggested, dont place a 0x prefix at all... (why create problems you dont need)

if you have to have the prefix, use it... if the prefix is '0x' use
`int i = Convert.ToInt32("0xFE".Substring(2), 16);` as *Alex K.* suggested

if it is not '0x', then it probobally a Base10 number:
`int i = Convert.ToInt32("342", 10);`